# How do I get a company activity feed using the REST API / Other Approach?

Tags: rest, api

Is it posible to get a Company activity feed using LinkedIn Url? It seems not posible, but I would like to be sure. In case that it's not posible: what other alternatives are over there? We were previously using a Linked URL that returned in plain HTML the Company activity feed but this URL is not working anymore (https://www.linkedin.com/biz//feed?start=0&v2=true )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any news about that question? I would like to achieve this too. I've seen this in LinkedIn docs: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/activity-feed but it seems that this API is only for some kind of Linkedin partner accounts... Please share if you've found something else ;) Regards

Comment: No news and since we want to implement this feature for Office 365, we have designed another approach what implies to publish LinkedIn content in a SPO list and then use Flow to publish in LinkedIn...this ensures we can easily get content from the list and show it using a LinkedIn look & Feel